# Using conditional operator in lambda expression in ForEach() on a generic List?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, lambda, conditional-operator

Is it not allowed to have a conditional operator in a lambda expression in ForEach?

```
List<string> items = new List<string>{"Item 1", "Item 2", "Item I Care About"};

string whatICareAbout = "";

// doesn't compile :(
items.ForEach(item => item.Contains("I Care About") ? 
whatICareAbout += item + "," : whatICareAbout += "");
```

Compilation error -> "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement"

Trying to use a normal if doesn't work either:

```
// :(
items.ForEach(item => if (item.Contains("I Care About")) {whatICareAbout += item + ", ";}
```

Just not possible?

Comment: Sheesh I am exceptionally impressed with the answers, all within minutes of asking :) I think @SLaks answers the intent of my question, but Aggregate() blows my mind! :) Thanks again everyone :)

Comment: You had a string expression as a type of conditional operator, and you needed a statement for your .ForEach() method. That's why compilation error was there.

Comment: @Roman - I get it now! I think of a ? x: y as short-hand for if (a) {x} else {y} but ? returns the value of x and y, which was a string in this case...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You're using the shorter form of lambda expressions, which only allow a single expressions.
You need to the long form, which allows multiple statements.

For example:

```
items.ForEach(item => {
    if (item.Contains("I Care About")) 
        whatICareAbout += item + ", ";
});
```

Answer (score 6):

What are you trying to acheive? Are you trying to form a string of comma separated items where they contain a particular value? In linq you would achieve this using the following:

```
 List<string> items = new List<string> { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item I Care About", "Item I Care About", "Item I Care About" }; 
 string whatICareAbout = items.Where(x => x.Contains("I Care About"))
                              .Aggregate( (y, z) => y + ", " + z);
```

The output from this is "Item I Care About, Item I Care About, Item I Care About".

Note: Aggregate is a great way of ensuring there is no trailing ","

Comment: Using `Aggregate` for sting concat is a very neat idea which I haven't thought of.  You could easily change it to use a `StringBuilder` because `StringBuilder` has a fluent interface.

Comment: hah, I was just adding an Aggregate() code sample to my initial answer... but I like yours better. +1 !

Answer (score 4):

The problem was that expression

```
item.Contains("I Care About") ? whatICareAbout += item + "," : whatICareAbout += ""
```

**is not a statement**. It just returns a value which has type `string`.

There is a trick to make it work (just for fun):

```
    items.ForEach(item => (item.Contains("I Care About") ?
    whatICareAbout += item + "," : whatICareAbout += "").GetType());
```

I simply added call to `.GetType()` method to create a statement from initial expression, and it compiled.

Comment: And for `.ForEach()` you needed a statement :)

Answer (score 1):

Try parentheses:

```
items.ForEach(item => item.Contains("I Care About") ? (whatICareAbout += item + ",") : (whatICareAbout += "") );
```

+= has a higher precedence than ?, that may be why you're getting the error. With parentheses, the error may go away.  Not 100% sure of this, though... lambda expressions may have additional restrictions which prevent use of assignment statements.

UPDATE:

Instead of multiple += statements, it's a lot cleaner to put the conditional on the right-hand side of the assignment, like this:

```
List<string> items = new List<string> { "one", "two", "three" };
string whatICareAbout = "";
items.ForEach(item => whatICareAbout +=  item.Contains("I Care About") ? (item + ",") : "");
```

UPDATE 2:

But it's even better to just use Aggregate() since it's designed for exactly this scenario.  Here's one sample:

```
string whatICareAbout = items.Aggregate("", (total, item) => item.Contains("I Care About") ? (total + item + ",") : total);
```

But I think [@Matt Breckon's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/200126/matt-breckon) answer above (that I just saw as I was about to post this)is even better than my example since it deals with removing the terminal ",". Look at his answer... :-)